# ACL configuration via GUI

Tags: networking

does anyone knows a GUI tool for netwotk ACL configuration?.The uesr will give some inputs via GUI then this should be transferred into ACL configuration.

The device is a CISCO router..

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com  (possibly superuser.com)

Comment: Futhermore, you'll need to specify the network equipment you are trying to configure, as this obviously matters much...

Comment: You're missing any sort of context. What is a "network ACL"? Is it Windows Policy access control lists? Some firewall? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for ur comments .. i got it now : [ACL EDITOR AND SIMULATOR](http://www.garethevans.info/products/acleditor)